# Why when requesting a token using the grant password and authorization code, I do not get the same claims?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a Identity Server client set up to be able to use the password and authorization code grants, I am able to use both, but when reviewing the tokens they do not contain the same claims, is this how its suppose to work or I am missing some configuration?

If this is how it works (different claims in each grant) when using the password grant should I use the Profile service to add the other claims?

Comment: Did you implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` yourself?

Comment: No, I haven't implemented.

Comment: You should, and fill the claimsprincipal with the claims you need to send (or inject ProfileService and let it populate the claims for you). Otherwise the default sends just `sub` claim IIRC. https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/0baf4d3313938d25957c8cde9aebf6eead99419d/src/AspNetIdentity/ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs#L59

Comment: Are you using IdS with ASP.NET Core Identity?

Comment: YesI am using ASP.NET Core Identity with IdS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`, and return the list of claims you need. The default implementation only sends the `sub` claim.

See [the example implementation for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/0baf4d3313938d25957c8cde9aebf6eead99419d/src/AspNetIdentity/ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs#L59) in IdentityServer repo.

Then modify it to send additional claims. Or use `ProfileService` to populate it:

```cs
public virtual async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, context.Password, true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var sub = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);

            _logger.LogInformation("Credentials validated for username: {username}", context.UserName);

            // return additional claims
            var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub, AuthenticationMethods.Password, claims);
            return;
        }
    // ... see the link above for a full implementation
}
```

You can also create a new `ClaimsPrincipal` to populate the results. See the `GrantValidationResult` constructor overloads for other options.